# Prometheus exporter for MySQL can can run SQL query delete update insert?

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

Hi anyone can answer about this questions ?

I have ubuntu cloud server, One of my office colleague has installed mysqld exporter in the cloud. The mysqld exporter always connected with my cloud server. I have check mysql username used into mysqld exporter, It has all permissions granted Insert, Update, Select all.

My Questions is

1. From Prometheus exporter for MySQL it is possible they can backup DB ?
2. From Prometheus exporter for MySQL it is possible he can real time monitor and real time modified raw ?
3. It is possible he can update, delete from Prometheus exporter for MySQL ?

Please answer these questions.

Comment: Do you know what Prometheus is or what an exporter does?

Comment: Do we talk about this: https://github.com/burningalchemist/sql_exporter